# Bcrypt argument error in change password route (if new password has not been used before)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I am making a route where a user can create a new password as long as they have not used it before.

The way I am doing this is by adding the hashed password to a 'usedPassword' array after the user creates an account OR modifies their password.

Then in my change password route I am hashing their newPassword, then comparing it to all the hashed passwords in the userPassword array to see if there is a match, if there is a match I will send the user an error telling them they cannot use the same password for their new one.

If there is no match, I clear all of their JWT tokens, assign newPassword to user.password (which is auto hashed, added to usedPassword array, and saved with middleware), finally create a new token (save it it middleware) and send back to client to update in keychain.

I get the following error when trying to compare hashedNewPassword with each previously used (hashed) password in my userPasswords array:

*../node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:137
error = new Error('data and salt arguments required');*
^

Where am I missing arguments so that I can compare hashedNewPassword against each hashed password in my usedPasswords array?

Thanks!

**Change Password Route**

```
router.patch("/api/user/change-password", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.user

     // hash newPassword to see if it has been used before in usedPassword array
    const hashedNewPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.newPassword, 10)

    user.usedPasswords.forEach(async (password) => {
       const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedNewPassword)
      if (match) {
        throw new Error(`You have already used this password`)
      }
    })

    // if no match, empty user's JWT tokens
    user.tokens = []

    // by assigning newPassword a pre(`save`) middleware will bcrypt hash the password
    user.password = user.newPassword
    await user.save()

    // make new token and save to user.tokens array with middleware
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken() 

    res.send(token)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})
```

**Hash text password pre middleware and push to user.usedPassword (Array)**

```
userSchema.pre(`save`, async function (next) {
  const user = this

  if (user.isModified(`password`)) {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
    user.usedPasswords.push(user.password)
  }

  next()
})
```

**Generate new token and save**

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
  const user = this
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "7 days",
  })
  user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token })
  await user.save()
  return token
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    user.usedPasswords.forEach(async (password) => {
       const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedNewPassword)
```

This is wrong.  You are hashing the new password then trying to compare the new hash to the list of usedPassword hashes.

You don't need to pre-hash the new password for this check.

```
    user.usedPasswords.forEach(async (password) => {
        // check the new password against previous passwords
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(user.newPassword, password)
```